# Почему отображается только часть обводки кнопки PyQt5?(Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

С помощью модуля PyQt5 я создал кнопку и в таблице стиля настроил некоторые параметры. Чтобы закруглить кнопку добавил ей обводку с круглыми краями. Чтобы скрыть обводку присвоил значению цвета обводки значение цвета окна. Почему-то обводка отобразилась не полностью(ниже оставлю картинку). Чтобы это было лучше заметно я сделал окно черным. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setStyleSheet('background-color: #000000;')

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
button.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {
                             background-color: #394976;
                             border-style: outset;
                             border-width: 10px;
                             border-radius: 10px;
                             border-color: #27304F;
                             color: white;
                             min-width: 10em;
                             padding: 6px;
                         }

                         QPushButton:pressed {
                             background-color: #303C60;
                             border-style: outset;
                         }''')
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily('Cera Pro')
font.setBold(True)
font.setPointSize(20)
button.setFont(font)

box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(box)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Это так `outset` рисуется. Вот про `border-style` http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-style

Comment: Получается, что как раз темная часть обводки нужного мне цвета. Я не понимаю, откуда берется светлая часть

Comment: Светлая это background-color: #394976, с нижней стороны к ней прибавляется тень

Comment: Даже не думал, что существуют такие справочники, очень нравится,  сейчас понял значение и других свойств, спасибо

Comment: @MAXIM045  если я правильно понял. то вам нужен `border-style: solid;` - так?

Comment: @S.Nick, да:) Тяжело искать то, о существовании чего даже не догадываешься. Я не думал, что существует справочник, в котором можно найти некоторые характеристики для таблиц стилей, и не знал, что основной этих таблиц является CSS

Comment: @MAXIM045 да таблицы `CSS` и  `QSS` - `почти идентичны`.